# How to get all the variables after each line and iteration of a for loop?

Tags: python

The `code` is received as a multi-line string. For example,

```
code = '''\
a = [1, 2]
for i in a:
    b = i*2'''
```

My current approach is to define a `list_vars` to store the variables, modify the original `code` string to add a line-marker and append the variables, and then `exec`, as follows ...

```
# list to store the variables
list_vars = []

# the modified code string
code = '''\
a = [1, 2]
for i in a:
    list_vars.append(['marker-1', locals().copy()])
    b = i*2
    list_vars.append(['marker-2', locals().copy()])'''

# exec the code, which will also store the vars in list_vars
exec(code)
```

If I run this and then `print(list_vars)`, I get ...

```
[['marker-1', {..., 'a': [1, 2], 'i': 1}],
 ['marker-2', {..., 'a': [1, 2], 'i': 1, 'b': 2}],
 ['marker-1', {..., 'a': [1, 2], 'i': 2, 'b': 2}],
 ['marker-2', {..., 'a': [1, 2], 'i': 2, 'b': 4}]]
```

The `...` above represents a bunch of other key-value pairs that `locals()` outputs, which I have omitted here.

This does the job, but there are a few issues.

1. It won't work for one liner for-loop (`for i in a: b = i*2`). In this case `list_vars` will contain only the last iteration result.
2. If I use a list instead of a variable to iterate (e.g., `for i in [1, 2]: ...` instead of `for i in a: ...`), the use of `locals()` does not record the list in `list_vars`. In this case, is there a way to record the list address as the key and the list itself as the value?
3. Another issue with using the `locals()` is that it outputs a bunch of other key-value pairs. It would be nice to record only the user-defined variables in the `code`.
4. The current approach litters the original `code` with `list_vars.append(...)`. It seems like there has to be a better way.
5. Another issue with littering the `code` with `list_vars.append(...)` is that it alters the line number (which could have been used as the line-marker).

**Is there a better approach to do this which will also address the issues listed above?**

Any tips or guidance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "The code is received as a multi-line string." where is the code received from?

Comment: Why do? `list_vars.append(['marker-1', locals().copy()])` before and after `b = i*2`?? Why not just `list_vars.append(b)`? Overall, it's really not clear to me waht you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga reading from a large file that contains data and code snippets among other things. I can parse the text to extract the data and code snippets. Different code snippets have different variable names and thus `locals()` will capture it all. Before and after because there can be many code lines after the `for` line and I want to store the variables at multiple points for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module and

- add entries in the tree using some code of yours, then
- call [compile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) and finally
- run it with [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

I tried it. Here the example:

```py
from ast import *
fa = parse('''
for i in [1,2]:
    b=2*i
    ''')
#dump(fa)
#and inspect

fa.body.insert(0,Assign(targets=[Name(id='dic', ctx=Store())], value=List(elts=[], ctx=Load())))
fa.body[1].body.insert(0,Expr(value=Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='dic', ctx=Load()), attr='append', ctx=Load()), args=[Dict(keys=[Constant(value='i')], values=[Name(id='i', ctx=Load())])], keywords=[])))

fa1=fix_missing_locations(fa)
co=compile(fa1,"<string>",mode="exec")
exec(co)
dic #[{'i': 1}, {'i': 2}]
```